# ios objective-c upload several photos to server in form of array

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, restful-url

Can anyone help me how to upload several photos to server in form of array that contains images data.

I did some research and I use 'multipart/form-data', but I'm confusing how to make it an array of images.

I want: pictures[image_1, image_2, image_3] in server side.

Here is what I did so far.

```
if (attachImages.count != 0) {

    for(int count = 0; count < attachImages.count; count++){

        NSLog(@"Body Image count: %d", count);
        UIImage *image = [attachImages objectAtIndex:count];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=picture.jpg\r\n", @"pictures[]"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData: imageData];
    }
    //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Thanks

Comment: Refer this :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/31651798/1275530

Answer (score 0):

So a good idea would be to turn the images into a data URI like so

```
NSData *imageDAta = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@",[imageDAta base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
```

than upload the data to your server, this will be the fastest way, thus not needinga multipart upload. When the image hits your server, you just need to turn the URI into data, depending on the language you are using there may be several packages