# Http Post Request with Two images files

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem. I need to send 2 jpg files to a server. I have to make a POST request with a body like that:

Body:
    front:  image file
    reverse:  image file

how can I make this post request with this two parameters?

I have a try with one parameter:

```
    static NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tarjetaPrueba.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)];


    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"front\"; \r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:imageData];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];
```

It is not working...why? I don´t know...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to content-type as multipart/form-data.
Add both images in a dictionary,convert it to NSData and finally append it to request body.

```
contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
```

Refer this link for help.

[How to send multiple files with post request? (objective-c, iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178113/how-to-send-multiple-files-with-post-request-objective-c-ios)